# Check if radio button is checked or not on form submit using Html Agility C#

Tags: c#, html, forms, html-agility-pack

I am using Html Agility to parse through the input elements and replace each input element with the value of the input element. I could parse through all other input elements but not a radio  button. I couldn't find if the radio button is checked or not.

This is my sample code. Please help.

```
    if (nodeType == "radio" && Request.Form[node.Id] != null) {
    node.SetAttributeValue("checked", "checked");
    node.SetAttributeValue("disabled", "true");
} else if (Request.Form[node.Id] != null) {
    fieldValue = Request.Form[node.Id].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox and radio type field does not get posted when they are not checked or selected.

So you need to check whether these fields exist in the post/request or not before setting any value or attribute.

I am not familiar with c# syntax so can not help you with the code